# What should I use to view for nested data?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to list the faculties at the university.Then I want to list the departments at the selected faculty,then I want to list the lessons at the selected department.

```
Faculties>|selected faculty|>departments>|selected dept|> list of lesson
```

What should I use to view for this structure?Which datatable/uicomponent is more suitable for me? I use Primefaces 5.0 in the view layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Datatable

You will have to implement some listeners (i.e. to fetch your next list based on the selected value) but that won't be a tough task since PrimeFaces datatables provide selection features (row click, button, ...) Just look at the showcase links below to get an overview.

Showcase: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml

### Master Detail

This is part of Primefaces Extension but seems to fit your needs because most of the logic is ready to use out of the box (ajax: update list view, update breadcrumbs, ...)

Showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/masterDetail/basicNavigation.jsf

### Tree

Either horizontal (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/htree/basic.xhtml) or vertical (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml). If you want to display your data within a table, consider using the TreeTable (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml).

However this will require to handle a TreeNode and it will, IMO, be way more difficult to build the TreeNode dynamically

Comment: I did not know 'Master Detail'.This solves my problem.So thanks.:)